# Format Sensor data marshalling in Sig Mesh Bluetooth

Tags: c++, c

I'm using sensor model and sensor mode setup for my project to read sensor data, I referenced example code of Cypress and STM electronics, but Sensor data marshalling of them not format the same, Which example is right for SIG Mesh?

STM Handler "Sensor data marshalling" below

```
    // Format A, define at document page 120
    byte[0] = ((format_a.property_id & 0x07) << 5) | (format_a.length <<1); 
    byte[1] = (format_a.property_id >> 3) & 0xFF; 

    // Format B, define at document page 120
    byte[0] = ((format_b.length <<1) | 0x01); 
    byte[1] = (uint8_t)format_b.property_id ;
    byte[2] = (uint8_t)(format_b.property_id >> 8);
```

Comment: Sorry for my English.